# Flex form layout - add first child vertically aligned with label

Tags: apache-flex, forms

In flex form layout

```
<mx:Form id="form">
        <mx:FormItem label="horizontal:">
            <mx:Text text="test"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

the output will be

horizontal 'test'

But my constraint is i want to align the textbox(first child of the form item ) vertically with the label. How can i do this ?Any inputs invited

Answer (score 1):

You could override the form / formitem class to change the layout approach by overriding updateDisplayList method.

You could also try something like this:

```
<mx:Form id="form">
        <mx:FormItem direction="vertical">
            <mx:Label text="horizontal:"/>
            <mx:Text text="test"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

Comment: Can u provide me some more inputs.. i looked at the source... But cant track it . can u provide me the sample overridden code.. Thanks !!!!

Comment: Learn about the Flex Component lifecycle.  Step through the lifecycle methods.  "Createchildren, commitProperties, updatedisplayList, and measure.  Review the code, figure out what it does.  See if it is possible to change it.

Answer (score 0):

For Spark-Forms it works differently. Take a look at this very good description: https://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Spark+Form

From the source above:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

    #stackedForm s|FormItem
    {
        skinClass : ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.StackedFormItemSkin");
    }
</fx:Style>



<s:Form id="stackedForm">                
    <s:FormItem label="Address" sequenceLabel="1." required="true" >
        <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
        <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
        <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="(ex. 123 Main Street)" baseline="24"/>
            <s:Button label="?" width="30" baseline="24" x="120"/>
        </s:helpContent>
    </s:FormItem>       
    <s:FormItem label="City" sequenceLabel="2." required="true">
        <s:TextInput width="100%"/>
    </s:FormItem> 
    <s:FormItem label="State" sequenceLabel="3.">
        <s:ComboBox dataProvider="{statesDP}" width="100%"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="ZipCode" sequenceLabel="4." required="true">
        <s:TextInput widthInChars="4" restrict="0123456789"/>
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Will appear in your profile" left="0" right="0" baseline="24"/>
        </s:helpContent>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```